# Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

My spring boot project uses `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` for caching on redis, Oracle database for persistent. It runs perfectly with current version 2.7.6. I've just upgraded to 3.0.5. The source code does change pretty much but this configuration for redis stays the same:

```java
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                .transactionAware()
                .build();
    }
```

Here is how I use `@Cacheable`

```java
    @Autowired
    private ConfRepository confRepository;

    @Cacheable(value = "configCache", key = "{#root.methodName, #key}")
    @Override
    public Optional<Config> getByKey(String key) {
        return confRepository.findByKey(key);
    }
```

I deploy my service with 2 instances. The problem is when a `key` is put to `Cacheable` in instance 1 cannot be deserialized by instance 2, i.e in above method, my first request to instance 1 to `getByKey` with the key `key1`, my second request to instance 2 also with the `key1` should hit the cache (get value from redis and return), but I got the stack trace:

```java
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementReader.read(DefaultRedisElementReader.java:46)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.read(RedisSerializationContext.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.deserializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:92)
    at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get(AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cache.transaction.TransactionAwareCacheDecorator.get(TransactionAwareCacheDecorator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:571)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:536)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:402)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)
    at vn.com.tcbs.h2h.biz.service.impl.ConfigManagerServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getGroupRole(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:211)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy201.getGroupRole(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:82)
    ... 219 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not identify any active SessionFactory having UUID 0105e7c4-c59a-46a6-a86e-23a65dde6ed6
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.SerializableProxy.retrieveMatchingSessionFactory(SerializableProxy.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.SerializableProxy.readResolve(SerializableProxy.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1190)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2606)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2457)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2257)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:509)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:467)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:71)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:73)
    ... 221 common frames omitted
```

Can anybody help me in this situation ?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after the upgrade?

Comment: yes, I have even deployed a new redis instance

Comment: I have the same error too. This error disabled me from doing hot deploy with spring-data, redis, and hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in Hibernate 6, the hibernate object caching is not working. So you need to load the full object if it's `FetchType.Lazy` and you need Lazy object properties and `unproxy` the object before caching.

To unproxy an object use the `Hibernate.unproxy` method.
**Updated code:**

```
@Cacheable(value = "configCache", key = "{#root.methodName, #key}")
@Override
public Optional<Config> getByKey(String key) {
    var config = confRepository.findByKey(key);
    var entity = config.isPresent() ? Hibernate.unproxy(config.get(), Config.class) : null;
    return Optional.ofNullable(entity);
}
```

I had a similar issue after upgrading to Hibernate 6 in Spring MVC. By `unproxy` the hibernate object before saving it into the cache solved the issue. Also, with spring security session I need to use record/POJO class for authentication object.

If issue still persist then use record/POJO class to be stored in cache. Because mapping of different entity also adds hibernate classes to serialization.

> Hibernate 6: Never store hibernate objects to cache when multiple servers uses same cache.

You can use [RedisInsight](https://redis.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/) to browse data stored in redis and inspect to get more details.

Comment: use POJO is the solution. thank you very much