# How to cache/deserialize a Hibernate proxy using Spring Cache with Spring Boot 3.2.0/Hibernate 6? (worked fine in Spring Boot 2.7/Hibernate 5)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-cache

After switching to Spring Boot 3.2.0, I'm now facing an issue with Spring Cache. Basically, I'm caching a JPA entity X that has one eagerly loaded ManyToOne entity O, which has a Lazy-loaded entity P. So that entity P is cached/serialized as `org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.SerializableProxy`, but is unable to be de-serialized when taken from cache by Spring (throwing "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not identify any active SessionFactory having UUID ..."). Although, it all worked fine in Spring Boot 2.7 (Hibernate 5.6).

Debugging showed that that `SerializableProxy` now has `sessionFactoryUuid` member in it, which is used in its updated `readResolve` method during deserialization and such Factory can't be found. It was not the case in Hibernate 5.6 and `sessionFactoryUuid` was not used, that's why it worked.

For the reference, here are 2 versions of that `readResolve` method, one that worked in Spring Boot 2.7 (Hibernate 5.6) and one that fails for me in Spring Boot 3.2 (Hibernate 6.4.1):

Older code:

```java
private Object readResolve() {
  BytecodeProvider bytecodeProvider = Environment.getBytecodeProvider();
  if ( !( bytecodeProvider instanceof BytecodeProviderImpl ) ) {
    throw new IllegalStateException( "The bytecode provider is not ByteBuddy, unable to deserialize a ByteBuddy proxy." );
  }
  HibernateProxy proxy = ( (BytecodeProviderImpl) bytecodeProvider ).getByteBuddyProxyHelper().deserializeProxy( this );
  afterDeserialization( (ByteBuddyInterceptor) proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer() );
  return proxy;
}
```

Newer code:

```java
private Object readResolve() {
  final SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory = retrieveMatchingSessionFactory( this.sessionFactoryUuid, this.sessionFactoryName );
  BytecodeProviderImpl byteBuddyBytecodeProvider = retrieveByteBuddyBytecodeProvider( sessionFactory );
  HibernateProxy proxy = byteBuddyBytecodeProvider.getByteBuddyProxyHelper().deserializeProxy( this );
  afterDeserialization( (ByteBuddyInterceptor) proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer() );
  return proxy;
}
```

First line of it uses "this.sessionFactoryUuid", which can't be found giving "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not identify any active SessionFactory having UUID 4abdfbc7-d762-4cfa-9a3f-e435fabe489c", where '4abdfbc7-d762-4cfa-9a3f-e435fabe489c' is that sessionFactoryUuid.

Currently, a workaround for me is specifically unproxy that proxy before caching, but it seems to be overkill and defeats the purpose of Lazy Loading. Is there another way? I've found a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958697) and Dhaval also mentioned unproxying as the only option. I don't want to spend resources for unproxying it (especially, when there is a collection of entities X) since I don't really care about that part after getting entity X from cache - that's why it's marked to be lazy-loaded. Maybe there are some Spring Cache or Hibernate settings that can help here? What's the best practice for such scenarios?

Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE 1:** Tried to use Andrey's suggestion from comments to specify `session_factory_name` for Hibernate as: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory_name=custom-hibernate-session` (had to be mindful of the fact that I'm configuring `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` manually, so used `hibernate.session_factory_name`). Although, got `org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [custom-hibernate-session]`, caused by `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specfy class name in enviroment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial`.

**UPDATE 2:** I was not sure about setting `hibernate.session_factory_name_is_jndi` to `false`, but when I did, that last error was gone and now my deserialization/reading from cache works fine! So that **`hibernate.session_factory_name` did the trick**! I just don't understand, why absence of this property breaks caching of entities with lazy-loaded associations completely and why it's like this by default. Anyway, thank you @AndreyB.Panfilov, I would not be able to solve it that quickly without your advice!

Comment: you may add something like `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory_name=my-cool-session-factory` into application.properties.

Comment: Thank you @AndreyB.Panfilov. Could you please elaborate on how do you think it might help? I've found this property only in the [docs for v3.3](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html), it says that adding this property means that the org.hibernate.SessionFactory will be automatically bound to this name in JNDI after it has been created. But [docs for 6.4](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html) don't have such property listed, so not sure if it can help...

Comment: [Naming the SessionFactory allows for it to be properly serialized across JVMs as long as the same name is used on each JVM](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/39457c5e121f6069c3d59005bd033f5c1b4d43f0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/PersistenceSettings.java#L72)

Comment: Thank you @AndreyB.Panfilov. So I have tried it, but it does not seem to work. Still having `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not identify any active SessionFactory having UUID 4abdfbc7-d762-4cfa-9a3f-e435fabe489c`. Will update my initial message with that try. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: you are definitely doing something wrong: everything does work as expected, please check the reproducible example: https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/gs-accessing-data-jpa/blob/306c81ae04b72673eb4f8f9bda487afe684dc2f3/complete/src/test/java/com/example/accessingdatajpa/SessionFactoryHasNameTest.java#L18

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov, I indeed was. I am initializing my `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` manually for custom stuff like named queries. Apparently, `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.*` has no effect in this case. So I was able to set it manually as `hibernate.session_factory_name`. BUT it tries to bind it in JNDI, failing with `org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [custom]`, caused by `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specfy class name in enviroment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial`. Trying to fix

Comment: I'm getting such exception as well, however it does not prevent persistence unit from starting

Comment: I was not sure about setting `hibernate.session_factory_name_is_jndi` to `false`, but when I did, that last error was gone and now my deserialization/reading from cache works fine! So that `hibernate.session_factory_name` did the trick! I just don't understand, why absence of this property breaks caching of entities with lazy-loaded associations completely and why it's like this by default. Anyway, thank you @AndreyB.Panfilov, I wouldn't be able to solve it that quickly without your advice! I think would be fair if you add your suggestion as an answer so people (including myself) could upvote!